# lcov or gcov -- how to large project analyze

Tags: gcov, lcov

I have large project to analyse. How to use gcov or lcov for it.
I found plenty of document for gcov for a single C file.
Not much document about lcov too. I'll be thankful  for any pointers or tips or links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Havn't you read the example (contained in the dist) and the docs about the gvoc, genhtml etc. There is described that you can analyze as many files as you wish (--zerocounters only for the first one) and then use the same analyze file for the others. So the result would be coverage for all files.

EDIT: Have you read the [README](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov/readme.php) on the web site

Comment: thanks checked it ..but still looking for something kind of tutorial or HOwTO on it.

Comment: May be you can a little more details on what you exactly searching for? The HowTo is described in the README...?

Answer (score 0):

Check the man pages for lcov - all options are described in there.